# Python Pandas Dataframe Memory Allocation in For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

import pandas as pd
import gc

I am running into difficulties managing my memory with Pandas DataFrames in a for loop. I am merging files about 10-20 GB large and then I am then doing groupby aggregations on (my total RAM is 128 GB so I should be mostly okay).

My work flow is set up thusly. Do some very memory intensive task, hit or not hit memory limit (128 GB), if hit limit then split up the data into chunks (do task on ith chunk, write to disk, do task on ith+1 chunk, append to disk). For an illustration see the psuedocode below:

```
def somethingfunc(x):
    #read a whole bunch of data w/ pandas, merge and do groupbys
    for i in range(x):

        #read data
        data1 = pd.read_csv(...)
        data2 = pd.read_csv(...)

        #get ith chunk of data1
        data1 = function_that_gets_ith_chunk_of_data1(data1) 

        #merge data
        datamerge = pd.merge(..., how = 'inner')  
        datamerge = datamerge.groupby(...)

        #either write chunk to memory or append
        if i == 0:
            datamerge.to_csv(...)
        elif i>0:
            datamerge.to_csv(..., mode= 'a', header ='none')



for x in range(10):
    try:
       somethingfunc(x+1)
       #do something memory intensive dividing data into (x+1) chunks
    except MemoryError:
       pass
    else:
       break
```

The problem comes when I go from doing the task with data in 1 chunk to 2 chunks. When I do the task in 1 chunk and it hits memory limit then I would like it to release all the data from the 1 chunk process before going onto 2. I have tried multiple ways of doing this (making sure the process is in its own function, explicitly calling gc.collect(), etc). I know my code works because I don't always hit the memory limit, but when I do, my chunk solution is not working. Does anyone know a good way to release all the data used by previous iteration?

It seems really odd that if a set of variables are created inside a function, and if said function terminates, that python not only saves those variables but they cannot be cleaned up by gc.collect()

**Edit:** I had my attention called to Dask, I am currently reading through the documentation but in the meantime if anyone knows how to do this in Dask that would be an acceptable answer as well

Comment: As a side remark of potential exploration for you, dask is designed to address this type of issues automatically for you so you don't manually take care of memory allocation and manual split of data frames etc

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't completely answer my question above but it seems the correct way to do this is in dask. This will implicitly do chunk iteration that I talk about above.